# bootstrap.min.css not loaded by Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, firebug

I am trying to use Bootstrap to customize the look of a few buttons on my page, and I included the JS and CSS as following:

```
link(href='/stylesheets/style.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='/stylesheets/jquery.dataTables.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', rel='stylesheet')
script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js')
script(src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js')
script(src='/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js')
script(src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js')
link(href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css', ref='stylesheet')
script(src='/javascripts/typeahead.bundle.js')
script(src='/javascripts/handlebars-v2.0.0.js')
script(src='/front_JS/searchFrontEnd.js')
```

I noticed that bootstrap.min.css is not loaded at all; and by using Firebug I saw the following (no '+' icon besides bootstrap.min.css):

[image: bootstrap.min.css not expandable in Firebug]

I tried both, Chrome and Firefox, and problem is the same.

My questions:

1. Do I need to include some other CSS or JavaScript in order to include the bootstrap.min.css?
2. Can I use Firebug to resolve such problem? I.e. will Firebug tell me what is missing here?

Comment: The weird thing is that this seems to work fine in fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/artt1130/a2zu0yy3/

Comment: Check the network tab to find out if the files are actually loaded.

Comment: no, it is not loaded seen from chrome network tab.

Comment: all other CSS and JS files are loaded except bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Try getting rid of the first slash: `/stylesheets/style.css` >> `stylesheets/style.css`

Comment: I tried. but it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe mispelling the Rel attribute :

```
link(href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css', ref='stylesheet')
```

Replace `ref` by `rel`

```
link(href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

Maybe...